# Como repartir el ancho de la página entre elementos usando CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente problema que me tiene desconcertado. Quiero ubicar un par de elementos, uno que tiene una serie de botones dentro y otro que ocupe el resto del tamaño disponible.

Esta imagen ilustra el resultado al que quiero llegar

[image: Ejemplo]

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="contenido">
        <!-- Debe ocupar el resto del espacio -->
    </div>
    <div class="botones">
        <!-- De acuerdo al texto y los botones puede ser más ancho pero siempre es fijo -->
        <button>Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parece una tarea sencilla pero no lo es. La raíz del problema es que el contenedor debe tener `width: 100%;` para que ocupe todo el ancho disponible y luego que el botón o los botones ocupen su tamaño, el resto debe ocuparlo el otro contenedor.

He probado ya usando `display` y `width: 100%`

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
}
.contenido {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.botones {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="botones">
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Evidentemente no funcionó ya que el `width` en `%` es con respecto al padre y se toma todo el espacio.

También probé con `calc`

```css
.contenedor {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.contenido {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 124px);
  background-color: blue;
}
.botones {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="botones">
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero no me sirve esa solución ya que tengo que obligar un tamaño fijo y puede que no me quepan los elementos.

¿Cómo pudiera lograr dicho layout?

De preferencia quisiera lograrlo sin usar `flexbox` ni `calc`, ni ninguna de las propiedades experimentales para hacerlo lo más compatible posible.

Comment: Flexbox no es tan experimental ;) depende realmente que tanto soporte de IE necesites. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Shaz Lo sé, por eso escribí "de preferencia". Intentando resolverlo me vino a la mente como podría haberse resuelto un problema similar hace unos años atras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según mi experiencia, lo más cercano (sin flexbox) sería haciendo que el contenedor y su contenido se comporten como "tablas", también le puedes poner anchos determinados si deseas:

```css
.contenedor {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.contenido {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.botones {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: violet;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="contenido">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="botones">
    <button>Ok</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta solución es buena pero aun deja un tamaño arbitrario para el contenedor de los botones. La solución ideal sólo debe ocupar el tamaño necesario y dejar el resto al otro contenedor.

Comment: Hice una modificación para dicho efecto.

Comment: Perfecto, esta es la solución que andaba buscando.